# EasyNetQ Topic Routing

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

Hi I have a question I have a main service and two client service, client service can be identified by unique id, not to communicate between sewer and clients I use RabbitMq with EasyNetQ, so what I want is to use single queue with some sort of routing so client will know, that this is not message is not for me and do not consume it. I thought topic based routing will do but something is wrong, and all clients get message alternately, once one client one another. And i do not want to use many queues and number of those clients can grow.

So my subscriber (client service side) looks like:

```
var topic = $"ProjectId.{ProjectId}.CabinId.{CabinId}";
var responseHandler = new Func<ManualServiceRequestMessage, Task>
(response => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"!!!!!!!!! {topic} !!!!!!!!!!");
    Console.WriteLine($"Response pid {response.ProjectId} cid {response.CabinId}");
})
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
   if (!task.IsCompleted && task.IsFaulted)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Message receive problem {response.ProjectId} frame type {response.CabinId} response id {response.RequestHash}");
   }
}));

bus.SubscribeAsync<ManualServiceRequestMessage>("LiveServer.ManualRequestQueue", responseHandler, x => x.WithTopic(topic));
```

Publisher (Server side)

```
var topic = $"ProjectId.{projectId}.CabinId.{cabinId}";
bus.PublishAsync(requestService, topic);
```

So anything I can do to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this on the subscriber (client) side: Instead of using `bus.SubscribeAsync`, call `bus.Advanced.Bind` and then `bus.Advanced.Consume`.
The `Advanced` field is of type `IAdvancedBus` and provides access to more convenient functions for queue communication and configuration. The `IAdvancedBus.Bind` method accepts a routing key and sets up basic configuration your subscriber needs to communicate with RabbitMQ, and the `IAdvancedBus.Consume` method actually starts listening for incoming messages asynchronously.